# Count differences between dates in same column

Tags: mysql

Table Applications

```
id | user_id | created_at
 1     2        week1
 2     3        week1
 3     2        week2
 4     5        week3
 5     3        week3
 6     2        week4
```

Count users who has applications last week but not current week. So for example for week2 it would return 1 and for week 3 it would return 1 and for week 4 it would return 2.

Expected outcome from query:

```
week    | difference
week2         1
week3         1
week4         2
```

Can I do it in a single query using UNION somehow or? I am kind of lost at the moment.

I know I could do a query for each week and then do multiple querys, but is it possible to do it in a single go?

Comment: Thats a bad way to store the data. A number representing the number of week in the year is better

Comment: @sagi how is your comment helping me closer towards solution? Yes the time is stored as date, that is not relevant in this question, thats why it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT created_at as week, count(user_id) as differences
   FROM Applications
WHERE created_at <> 'week1'
GROUP BY created_at
```

Comment: if current week is week1